# Want to retrieve emails from gmail

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I want to fetch emails from my gmail account. I did use that code but there is nothing showing on the front screen except not stop loop. I didn't understand where i am wrong because my port is right . I have also enabled the IMAP setting in my `GMAIL account`. I am using windows 7. please help me to resove this issue.

```
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$connection = imap_open($server, 'abc@gmail.com', 'abc');


$emails = imap_search($connection,'UNSEEN');
if($emails) {

    rsort($emails);

    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
      $overview = imap_fetch_overview($connection,$email_number,0);
      print_r($overview);
      echo $overview[0]->subject."\n";
      $message = imap_fetchbody($connection,$email_number,1);

      echo $message;
    }

} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server should probably look like the following:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
```

You can find a good demo on how to set this up here: http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: what exactly is looping? Notice that you don't have "image" or "INBOX" specified in your example.

Comment: I dont understand what exact is looping. I messed up with this code from today. Please help me. Atleast tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: Outside of the `$hostname`, I don't see anything wrong, without more info I can't provide any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try, 
`$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';` it will work, and once you fetched the mail, the mail will mark as read.